# How do I create a view with the distinct values from 1 table and values from another table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a view that has each item with 26 numbers as the second row.

```
item_no   loc
 456       00
 456       01
 456       02
```

etc

I can get a distinct list of the items with

```
select distinct item_no from imitmidx_sql
```

and I can get the distinct 26 locations from

```
select distinct loc from iminvloc_sql
```

how do I join these into 1 view
with each item having 26 locations

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
select distinct item_no,b.loc from IMITMIDX_SQL a
join (select distinct loc from IMINVLOC_SQL) b  on a.item_no = a.item_no
```